# Repeat values of vector based on an index vector

Tags: r

I am trying to practice using functions from the apply() family. I want to make a function that returns a weighted mean based on an index. In this case the vector "k". Here is my sample data:

```
#gen data

i=c(1,2,3,4)
j=c(1,2,1,2)
k=c(1,2,3,1)
t=c(1,1,1,1)

w=c(5,10,15,20)
d=c(4,5,10,2)
df<- data.frame(i,j,k,t,w,d)


#weighted mean

w=df[,"w"]
y=df[,"d"]
index=df[,"k"]
```

Next, I have a problem with the dimensions of vectors p and s.

```
p <- w*y
s <- array(tapply(w,index,FUN=sum))

dim(p) = 4
dim(s) = 3
```

I would like to repeat the value of s[1]=25  based on the index vector k=c(1,2,3,1) so that s[4]=25 as well!

The end goal is to be able to compute:

```
r <- p/s
```

Comment: Because your `index` is not unique

Comment: Do you just want `s` to be of the same length, Does this work : `s <- rep(s, 2)[1:length(index)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One line solution for `weighted mean` using `data.table`

```
> library(data.table)
> setDT(df)[, weighted.mean(d, w), by=k]

   k   V1
1: 1  2.4
2: 2  5.0
3: 3 10.0
```

**Solution Based on your approach-**

You can use `data.table` package to do that-

```
p <- setDT(df)[,w*d,by=.(k)][,lapply(.SD, sum),by=k][,V1]
s <- array(tapply(w,index,FUN=sum))
r <- p/s

[1]  2.4  5.0 10.0
```

**Input Data-**

```
i=c(1,2,3,4)
j=c(1,2,1,2)
k=c(1,2,3,1)
t=c(1,1,1,1)

w=c(5,10,15,20)
d=c(4,5,10,2)
df<- data.frame(i,j,k,t,w,d)
```

**Note**- You need to collapse `sum` by `index` before dividing it with `s`